# Powershell: XML import doesn't pass the values from XML

Tags: json, xml, powershell

Trying to import a values from Xml

```
<configuration>
<properties>
<subtype type="integer">1</subtype>
<name type="string">packer-centos8-base-g2-10</name>
</properties>
<settings>
<processors>
<count type="integer">4</count>
</processors>
<memory>
<bank>
<dynamic_memory_enabled type="bool">False</dynamic_memory_enabled>
<limit type="integer">1048576</limit>
<reservation type="integer">512</reservation>
<size type="integer">4096</size>
</bank>
</memory>
</settings>
<AltSwitchName type="string">Default Switch</AltSwitchName>
<boot>
<device0 type="string">Optical</device0>
</boot>
<secure_boot_enabled type="bool">False</secure_boot_enabled>
<notes type="string"> </notes>
<vm-controllers>
<scsi ChannelInstanceGuid="x">
<controller0>
<drive0>
<pathname type="string">
C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\hyperv314337150\packer-centos8-base-g2-10.vhdx
</pathname>
<type type="string">VHD</type>
</drive0>
</controller0>
</scsi>
</vm-controllers>
</configuration>
```

Output from the Powershell commands

```
PS C:\San\SV65\ps> $jvariables=Get-Content -Raw -Path '.\variables-ps.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
PS C:\San\SV65\ps> $VMXml = Get-ChildItem -path $jvariables.vmfp -recurse -include *.xml

PS C:\San\SV65\ps> write-host $jvariables.vmfp

C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-10\Virtual Machines\

PS C:\San\SV65\ps> write-host $VMXml

C:\San\SV65\hyper-packer\hyper-packer\output-centos8-10\Virtual Machines\box.xml

PS C:\San\SV65\ps> write-host $VMbox

PS C:\San\SV65\ps>
```

$VMbox gets a null value, I am trying to extract a value from the xml

```
 $name = $VMbox.configuration.properties.name
```

is this because of the spaces in btn "Virtual Machines"? in $VMXml?

If its gets populated from variables.json

```
$jvariables=Get-Content -Raw -Path '.\variables-ps.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

{
"psfp":  "C:\\San\\SV65\\ps\\",
"vmfp": "C:\\San\\SV65\\hyper-packer\\hyper-packer\\output-centos8-10\\Virtual Machines\\",
"psmp": "C:\\San\\SV65\\ps\\",
"vmname": ""
}
```

How to add the values in the variable as 'value' in this format?

Even if I add, it's not getting executed in the powershell.

In summary, I want to extract the path from json and try to get the value from Xml and use in the code.

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning a value to ```$VMBox``` anywhere in your "Output from the Powershell commands". Have you missed a command in that sample?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to load the xml file after you get the path in variable `$VMXml`.
Also, it is very likely/possible that by using

```
$VMXml = Get-ChildItem -path $jvariables.vmfp -recurse -include *.xml
```

this variable holds an **array** of FileInfo and/or DirectoryInfo objects, so better use something like

```
$VMXml = Get-ChildItem -Path $jvariables.vmfp -Recurse -Filter '*.xml' -File | Select-Object -First 1
```

to get just one FileInfo object.

Then instantiate the variable `$VMbox` using

```
[xml]$VMbox = Get-Content -Path $VMXml.FullName
```

and get the values from that with your code `$name = $VMbox.configuration.properties.name`

Hope that helps